# Finding max value in list, that is an attribute in object which is in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program in python 3 that is sort of simulating contests between different players, which are throwing a ball.

I have a list with players-objects, the objects have the attributes name, average length of throws, standard deviation of throws, and lastly: an attribute of the form a list, where every index contains the multiple throws that the player preforms during eack contest. (To clarify, on index 0 there would be for example 6 throws from the first contest, on index 1 there would be 6 throws from the second contest and so on). There are multiple players of course. I now need to find a way to determine which player is the winner of each and every contest and count the number of wins for each player. I'm kind of stuck on the whole finding the winner-thing, but here is what I've thought of so far:

```
def winner(self):
    for player in players:
        winner= max(players, key = attrgetter("self.results"))
```

The Player objects are created through this class:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, mean, standardDeviation):
        self.name = name
        self.mean = mean
        self.standardDeviation = standardDeviation
        self.results = []
```

I'm pretty sure that what I've written above will not get me anywhere, so do any of you have any tips?

Comment: What's a "contest" consist of?

Comment: Good question, sorry I didn't include that in the initial post! 

During the program, the user chooses the number of throws per player and the number of contests, so a contest consists of a number of throws per player, which I've got from the previous part of the program, where each throw is a normally distribueted number given from the function random.normalvariate (hence every player-object having a average and standard deviation value for their throws). 

My first language isn't english, so if there is anything further that is off with my description of my problem, please let me know

Comment: So for each contest, the winner is the person(s) who got the highest single dice throw (which is the sum of die values within a throw) out of the number of throws allowed for each person in that contest?

Comment: Well like this: there are four players, each throw n times during one contest. There is a method in the class Contest which runs the contests, so that each player throws n times, and the n throws are appended to a temporary list called temporaryList, which is appended to results, so on one index in that list there will be multiple throws, and one index is one contest. The winner is the player/players with the longest throw (largest number) and this winner and its winner-throw is to be found in the list results. So there is no sum involved in this; the throws are not to be added to eachother.

Comment: So, the winner/winners is that player/players that got the longest throw (largest number) out of all the throws in the contest (the list will contain, as I said, all contests) and all players will throw the same number of times. And the players-object, with the results-list as an attribute, will be in a list called players.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version of something with just a simplified`Player`class to help you get started. It handles ties where more than one player threw the ball the same longest distance as another.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, results):
        self.name = name
        self.results = results

def find_winners(players, num_contests):
    winners = []  # one (or more) player entries per contest
    for icontest in range(num_contests):
        contest_winners = []  # may hold multiple players if there are ties
        contest_longest_throw = -1
        for player in players:
            player_longest_throw = max(player.results[icontest])
            if player_longest_throw > contest_longest_throw:
                contest_longest_throw = player_longest_throw
                contest_winners = [player]
            elif player_longest_throw == contest_longest_throw:
                contest_winners.append(player)
        winners.append(contest_winners)
    return winners

# test data
players = [Player('Name1', [(7, 8, 9), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]),
           Player('Name2', [(4, 5, 6), (8, 9, 10), (6, 7, 8)]),
           Player('Name3', [(1, 2, 3), (5, 6, 7), (9, 10, 11)]),
           # add one that will tie with first player
           Player('Name4', [(7, 8, 9), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)])]

# assumes length of first player's results is number of contests
winners_found = find_winners(players, len(players[0].results))

print("Contest  Winner(s)")
for icontest, contest_winners in enumerate(winners_found, start=1):
    print('{:^7}  {}'.format(
        icontest, ', '.join(player.name for player in contest_winners)))
```

Output:

```
Contest  Winner(s)
   1     Name1, Name4
   2     Name2
   3     Name3
```

Comment: Hm, I believe you are, however - the output is not supposed to be numbered but simply "Name Winner-throw", for example "Martin 20,21", so the list (I suppose) must also include the winning throw of the winner. Also, the whole program is written in classes (as it is an requirement in the course). Therefore, the number of contests are a variable in a method in another class (class Contests), but I suppose that could be accessed via a reference?

Comment: Or actually, I don't follow the latter part of your example - you have the list winners in the first function for the winners and then you write, winners = find_winners(players, len(players[0].results))
I don't get how/why you used them on both these places?

Comment: You can format the output however you wish, I was showing the results of calling `find_winners()`. The first value printed is just indicating which contest the result applies to. There are two variables named `winners`. One is local to the aforementioned function and its value is determined there. The other variable is a global which just happens to have been given the same name as the local one. It gets assigned the value that the function returns when it is called and passed the list of `Player` objects as its first argument.

Comment: Okay, I see! How could one solve the situation where multiple players have the same longest throw?

Comment: See the latest update which handles more than one player having the same longest throw.